# Satellite Internet Connection slows localhost database connection even though it's localhost?

Tags: php, apache, mariadb, latency

At a friend's house I noticed that the high latency (1,500ms / 1.5 seconds) is effecting PHP connecting to MariaDB databases; *all* localhost. Requests are spiking upwards to 20 seconds. The host for the connection is 127.0.0.1 which obviously does not need to resolve to a host. How do I prevent local requests from wasting time trying to resolve to a host?

Comment: Is it resolving or recompiling?  Is it running under IIS?  Is it part of a .NET website?

Comment: How does `/etc/hosts` look? Are you certain you are connecting to `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`?

Comment: @JNevill No changes to the `hosts` file and yes, it's the IP address, not `localhost` in the connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the db with `--skip-name-resolve` (or alter the configuration accordingly). This should speedup the connect, but you can not specify a hostname in the GRANT permissions.